# How to marshal and unmarshal abstract classes in JAX-RS using jersey and MOxy

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, moxy

Hi I want to update jersey 1.x to 2.x and Jackson to MOxy.
But I don't know how to marshal and unmarshal abstract classes in MOxy.

In Jackson it did work completely using Custom Resolver.
Here is my sample code.

beans

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonTypeIdResolver(AnimalResolver.class)
abstract class animal{
    protected String name;
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    private CatBreed breed;
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    private DogBreed breed;
}
```

resolver

```
public class AnimalResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase{
    ....
    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object context, Class<?> suggestedType) {
        if (Dog.class.isAssignableFrom(suggestedType)) {
            return "dog";
        } else if (Cat.class.isAssignableFrom(suggestedType)) {
            return "cat";
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) throws IOException {
        TypeFactory typeFactory = (context != null) ? context.getTypeFactory() : TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
        if ("dog".equals(id)) {
            return typeFactory.constructType(Dog.class);
        } else if ("cat".equals(id)) {
            return typeFactory.constructType(Cat.class);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

How can I do like this in MOxy?

Comment: [oops sorry :-)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) Meant to link to @XmlSeeAlso

Comment: thanks but still not work my code. My API is
https://gist.github.com/82p/04a65671f3c38737848bf906b351c144

Sorry I can not paste my code here...

Comment: This test result is   

    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[{"name":"Rocky"[,"breed":"GOLDEN_RETRIEVER"},{"name":"Tigger","breed":"ABYSSINIAN]"}]> but was:<[{"name":"Rocky"[},{"name":"Tigger]"}]>  

and  

    java.lang.AssertionError: 200 OK? Expected: is <200> but: was <500>`

Comment: Can you add another gist with your model classes

Comment: [This is my all code](https://github.com/82p/jersery-test)

Comment: And I want to work [this test](https://github.com/82p/jersery-test/blob/master/src/test/java/jp/hani/jersey/api/AnimalApiTest.java) collectly... (put test may be wrong)